# Synchronously process Observable to prevent too many HTTP requests from timing out using rxjs Angular and ngrx

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5, ngrx

I have the following code. It gets an array of Patients and builds a rows object `this.rows` that I show in a table on the frontEnd of this angular 4 component (I am also using rxjs 5.5).

My issue is the hasAlert property of each row is assigned by a call to hasAlerts(). In the HasAlerts method, I make an http request, for each patient via `this.dataService.fetchItems<Observation>(`.

**When there are many patients, too many HTTP requests will occur asynchronously and they will start to fail (timeout) from HasAlerts(). Is there a way to throttle this,or process one Observable at a time from hasAlerts()?**

Below are possible ways to solve this

1. I think concatMap may be helpful but I am not sure how to use it. Also should use it to process each patient/row or should try and aggregate each hasAlert() observable into a list and then try and use concatMap to process them one at a time?
2. A workaround is the patientsAlertsProcessed variable wrapper that I added with the comment // is done to throttle the hasAlertsMethod. I limit it to only hit that method for 15 times to avoid timeout issues. This is not ideal because I am not able to start it up again once those 15 async requests complete.

Code is below

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new patients.Load([]));

    this.patients$ = this.store.select(fromPatients.getAll); 
    var patientsAlertsProcessed =0;
    this.patients$.debounceTime(2000).map(p =>{//Emits Observable<Patient[]>s, the debounceTime is to take the last one as it builds up
      this.rows = p.map(pat => {// p = Patient[], iterate through the array of patients
        var observations=0;
        var rowX= {
          username: pat.username,
          id: pat.id,
          hasAlert:false, 
        };

        if (patientsAlertsProcessed<15){// this is done to throttle the HasAlerts Method
          this.hasAlerts(pat).do(x => {
            observations++;
            if (observations>0)
            {
              rowX.hasAlert=true;
            }
          }).subscribe();
          patientsAlertsProcessed++;
        }
        return rowX;
      });
    }).subscribe(
       ()=> { },
       ()=> {
        this.table.recalculatePages();
      }
    );

  }
  hasAlerts(pat: Patient): Observable<Observation> {
    var obs$= this.dataService.fetchItems<Observation>(// this is making an HTTP get request 
        "Observation",
        null,
        pat.id
      ).filter(function (x){
        if (x.category.coding[0].code == "GlucoseEvent"){ 
            return true;
        }
        else{
          return false; 
        }
      }
    );
    return obs$;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try something along these lines.

```
const concurrency = 10; 
const rowsWithAlerts = [];

this.patients$.debounceTime(2000)
.switchMap(patients => Observable.from(patients)) // patients is of type Patient[]
.mergeMap(patient => {
   rowsWithAlerts.push(patient);
   this.hasAlerts(patient).do(
   hasAlertsResult => {
     // here you have hold to both the patient and the result of
     // hasAlerts call
     patient.hasAlerts = hasAlertsResult;
   }}), concurrency)
.subscribe(
   () => this.rows = rowsWithAlerts;
)
```

The key here is to use the `mergeMap` operator with the concurrency level set to a value, in this example 10 but clearly can be anything.

This allows to limit the number of observables to which you subscribe at the same time, which in your case means to limit the number of http calls you make.

Comment: Going to try this, I noticed you have a mastery of rxjs. Are there any resources that were helpful when you became familiar with rxjs?

Comment: the logic where I set this.rows would i do that in a block after the => in the switchMap line?

Comment: I would not advice to do this. You have to consider that the `patients` array you get as parameter of switchMap is a different array than the one you get with `rowsWithAlerts`. They are different instances of array potentially holding different instances of Person.

Comment: Where am I supposed to assign username ID and has alerts as properties to rowX in your example? Also in the switch map line observable.from(p) the p is undefined

Comment: You are right, it should not be p but patients within `switchMap`. I have also updated my answer, so that you set the `hasAlerts` flag for each patient and push each patient into a rows array.

Comment: Not all patients will have alerts. Is there any way I can also capture them in my rows.The block for hasAlertsResults => will only capture the patients with the alerts. Is there a way to also add the other patients where the hasAlerts() method wont return any observable. Id would like them both to be included in the rows data structure the only difference is with the property hasAlerts: set to true or false

Comment: it should be sufficient to move the `rowsWithAlerts.push(patient);` line before the `hasAlertsResult =>` block. I have edited the response accordingly

Comment: I dont believe I can do any logic there before the hasAlertsResults due to an error"Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PartialObserver<Observation>'."

For example I cannot put a console.log there because it thinks its an argument for the .do()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170312/discussion-between-picci-and-frank-visaggio).